# The best method to create typewriter effect?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, type-conversion, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I am creating a game that focuses on character to character interactivity. So when you interact with a character a chat box opens and the characters start talking to one another. I have the text setup like an old school typewriter effect one letter at a time. As of now I create it by typing each letter on separate frames and have them play through. When it gets to then end of the sentence in order for the user to go on to the next sentence I have a button that they tap Here is the code:

```
private function nextConvo(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        nNext += 1;
        trace(nNext);

        if (nNext == 1)
        {
            conversation.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }else
        if (nNext == 2)
        {
            conversation.gotoAndPlay(117);
        }
    }
```

As you can see i set it up to play the next frame with the new conversation so on and so on. I have a lot more text to do I realized it will be really time consuming and wonder if there is a easier way.

A method to where it types the string in the text box and I can still use my button so when the user wants to see the next conversation they can press the next button.

I saw a video here of someone showing the code way of doing it but Not sure how I would implement the button without having to add a lot of new mouse listeners and timers. [Code Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=205&v=usdJOktU-Gk)

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think a far better and flexible approach would be to create it by code - add `enterFrame` listener, and on each frame (you can even use `Timer` if you want to change speed) you can set the text to a text field. So on 1st frame you set 1st character. On second frame - 1st + 2nd character and so on. You just slice the text to the specific frame. You are currently doing exactly the same but with Timeline, which will get you in hell :P If you have trouble setting up the code - let me know.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking. I saw the code method with a timer being used as I put a link to the video above. The code was short and simple but I think the only problem I would run into with that code would be how to add my continue button I would have to add multiple Listeners over and over again. But ill give it a try from what you mentioned thanks @AndreyPopov

Comment: `if(textfield.text==sourceText) { continueButton.visible = true; timer.stop(); }` something along those lines would be fine.

Comment: what about this one http://greensock.com/forums/topic/1605-typewriterplugin-and-decodertextplugin/

Comment: Hey @harilalkm I will Definitely try that and see how it goes. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Omg, yes, you will go nuts if you show one character per frame :)

The idea is to have a function to handle this for you that you have ONCE somewhere (for example, on your main timeline). Then you can call it from everywhere and just pass the text, textfield to type into and a button.

```
private var _myText:String;
private var _myTextField:TextField;
private var _myButton:Button;
private var _currentCharacterPosition:int;

public function typeText(text:String, myTextField:TextField myButton:Button):void
{
    _myText = text;
    _myTextField = myTextField;
    _myButton = myButton;
    _myButton.visible = false;
    _currentCharacterPosition = 1;
    typeNextCharacter();
}

private function typeNextCharacter():void
{
    _myTextField.text = _myText.substr(0, _currentCharacterPosition);

    if (_currentCharacterPosition == _myText.length)
    {
        // all text is typed out, show your button
        myButton.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // type next character. 0.2 is the delay between letters (200 ms)
        _currentCharacterPosition++;
        setTimeout(typeNextCharacter, 0.2);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have the textfield and button in the same place (same frame), you could then do this in that frame:

```
_root.typeText("This is my text to type out", myTextField, myButton);
```

Comment: I won't advise using `setTimeout` like.. never. Either use `Event.ENTER_FRAME` or `Timer`. Timeouts are hard (and even sometimes impossible) to manage (stop/clear).

Comment: Yeah true, setTimeout is not a very good solution but easier to use for the explanation here :) Timer is the way to go

Comment: Hey thanks for this @Philarmon this is what I was looking for! I do have a question though. So I would add this with my own text of course to the next frame  on my timeline _root.typeText("This is my text to type out", myTextField, myButton); ? What If I use Flash Develop for all my coding? Is there I way I can implement this using my main engine Class? Ill try it out in the mean time.

Comment: Sure, then you just place the code into a class and call this function within that class